# https, and http on the same application in tomcat

Tags: http, tomcat, https

Can I make a web application in tomcat accept both http and https requests?,

Https and http requests need to call different servlets in the same application.

Comment: Read Tomcat SSL HOW-TO: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Comment: I read it and it doesn't tell how to call two servlets for http and https requests

Comment: It tells how to turn on HTTPS for Tomcat so that your web applicaiton can accept both HTTP and HTTPS requests. You haven't asked at all how to distinguish HTTP/HTTPS requests in servlets. Now, do you have HTTPS already configured in Tomcat?

Comment: Based on your incoming request, either http or https, you want to invoke different servlets? Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: I already have https configured in tomcat and I can distinguish between http and https using HttpServetRequest.getscheme, but I want to call two difference servlets of the same application for each of http and https. My second stmt in the question clearly states this.

Comment: @LoyalBanana You question is very unclear. The 'Can I make a web application in tomcat accept both http and https requests?,' is more emphazied. And the actual stuff you wanted is not very clear.

Comment: The second statement is a statement, not a question. In normal English this is to be interpreted as "additional background explanation" why you need to accept both HTTP and HTTPS. Your *real* question so far is how to accept both HTTP and HTTPS in Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

No. By default the container cannot dispatch HTTP to one servlet and HTTPs to another servlet. You need to have a filter to this. Based on the incoming scheme(`HttpSerlvletRequest.isSecure()`), the filter should redict to Secure Servlet or Unsecure Servlet.

Comment: that doesn't exactly answer my question, my question is how can I call two different servlets from the same application for http and https requests

Comment: This `web.xml` entry is merely telling that the transport is required to be HTTPS, it is surely not turning on HTTPS support in the servletcontainer.

Comment: @BalusC From the question 'Https and http requests need to call different servlets in the same application., i was thinking he is looking for configuring a webapp, where some pages can be accessed by http and some only by https. Am i wrong?